# Pass the info from custom cell to another viewController (Swift 3)

Tags: ios, swift

I want to pass the article headline from the custom cell to another viewController. I have a separate class for the tableViewCell and a class for loading the news. Now I want that headline to be displayed in another viewController.

Here is where I load data into the custom cell

```
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt     indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? newsCellTableViewCell
    let news = newsData[indexPath.row]
    cell?.headline.text = news.title
    cell?.excerpt.text = news.text

    Alamofire.request(news.imgUrl).responseImage { response in
        debugPrint(response)

        print(response.request as Any)
        print(response.response as Any)
        debugPrint(response.result)
        let cellImage = response.result.value
        if let image = response.result.value {
            print("image downloaded: \(image)")
        }
        cell?.thumbnailImage.image = cellImage
    }
    print(news.imgUrl)
    return cell!
}
```

Here is my prepareForSegue

```
  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier "showArticle" {
        var selectedRowIndex = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
        var gotoVC:ArticleViewController = segue.destination as ArticleViewController
    }
}
```

My outlets for the headline, image and excerpt are in the custom cell class, so I can not easily access them in this method.

In the destinationViewController I put one label outlet called articleTitle and one string variable called articleTitleString which should receive passed data.

Comment: You don't need to (and shouldn't) pull the data out of your cell in `prepareForSegue`.  You have the index path for the selected row, so you can access the `newsData` for that row just like you do in `cellForRowAt` and pass the data to your next view controller from your model.

Comment: @dan I don't get it. How can I than choose from which label to get data? I have two labels in a cell and one image view.

Comment: Could you please explain it a bit more?

Comment: In your `cellForRowAt` method you get an `indexPath`, then you use it to get the correct `news` item from your `newsData` array and pass the values to your cell.  Your `prepareForSegue` method should do the exact same thing.  You already figured out how to get the `indexPath` through `indexPathForSelectedRow`, now use that to get the correct `news` item from your `newsData` array and pass the values to your destination view controller.

Comment: @dan I still can not figure it out

      if segue.identifier == "showArticle" {
            let news = newsData[indexPath.row] as newsCellTableViewCell
                    let destination = segue.destination as? ArticleViewController,
                 slectedRowIndex = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row
                    destination?.articleTitleString =

Comment: Can't you just do `gotoVc.yourVariable = newsData[selectedRowIndex]` ?

Comment: I tried that as well but does not work! How is it possible that such simple thing can get very difficult?